# How to show float number on a video?

Tags: opencv

I'd like to show some float number as the number of people on the video. Here is one example.[image]

Is there any method to do this?

Comment: Are you asking how to draw numbers on an image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert a `float` to `std::string` like this:

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << 0.5f;
std::string s = ss.str();
```

then you can pass `s` to PutText

Comment: Cool! That's exactly what I want.